# mongo db with node js not able to run sum query on string object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

so i have this type of documents in mongo db.

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("599ccc896f16e74a3e26f1a9"),
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-22T17:14:59.000Z"),
        "header" : {
            "uniq_id" : "9951503422099.16801274",
            "request" : "GET /v1/api/payload"
            "username" : "user1",
            "data_length" : "201",
            "status" : "200"
        }
    },
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("599ccc896f16e74a3e26f1a9"),
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-22T17:15:59.000Z"),
        "header" : {
            "uniq_id" : "9951503422099.16801274",
            "request" : "GET /v1/api/payload"
            "username" : "user1",
            "data_length" : "301",
            "status" : "200"
        }
    }
```

here in the above document the data_length is in `String`
now what i am trying to do is to group the similar types of username and add their `data_length` and also count the data this is what the query looks like

```
Model.aggregate([ {$match: {
            timestamp: {
                $gte: ISODate("2017-08-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
                $lt: ISODate("2017-08-22T23:59:00.000Z")
            }
        }},
        {
              $group: {_id: {"username": "$header.username", "request": "$header.request"},

                       response_size: {$sum :parseInt("$header.data_length")},
                       count: {$sum: 1}   
              }
        }
        ])
```

the result of the above query looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "username" : "user1",
        "request" : "GET /v1/api/payload"
    },
    "response_size" : nan,
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

even if putting the `parseInt` in `data_length` the result i am getting is NaN. but the `response_size` should come 502
how can i get the sum of `data_length` properly

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change your data_length fields to type int ("data_length": 301 instead of "data_length": "301")? It appears to me your mongodb server isn't configured to allow javascript scripts - this is disabled by default and needs to be enabled.

Comment: i am doing this by node js .. it possibly should work there , but still not working

Comment: MongoDB is actually very typed in how it stores values.This is specifically about how you handle the MongoDB stored data inside of Mongo itself. I don't know what modules, etc you are using so:
1) If you have access to the MongoDB directly, go in and manually change the data; but
2) If something in your code is forcing "data_length" into being a string when being stored this problem will resurface every time; however
3) Try making sure "data_length" is an integer and then store.

Comment: actually there is an already existing process or APIs which stores the data in data_length as string and it is also being used at many places so it is not feasible for me to change the data type directly into db. thats why i was looking for a workaround

Comment: Things add up and add up, don't they? It seems to me your only answer is to come up with a string to string comparison - otherwise you'll have to retrieve all the records and do the comparison in your javascript code.